# QML Qt 5.2 problem with mp4 video

Tags: application-development, video, ubuntu-touch, qt, gstreamer

I have qt 5.2(ubuntu sdk) installed on Ubuntu 14.04

When I try to run QML code:

```
MediaPlayer {
    id: mediaPlayer
    source: "../path/test.mp4"
    autoPlay: true
}

VideoOutput {
    id: video
    width: screen.width
    height: screen.height
    source: mediaPlayer
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
}
```

I get:
Error: "Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in."

Note:

1) I can play test.mp4 in Totem

2) I can play ogv files with above code

What am I missing?
Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras` won't help you because the QML QtMultimedia component still uses the (old) gstreamer 0.10 plugins, check the Qt Multimedia (Qt 5) [planning](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Multimedia) to see:

> Port the GStreamer backend to GStreamer 1.0 (currently 0.10).

And since MP4 support in 0.10 is provided by the ffmpeg plugin you need to set up the following PPA to enable MP4 support for 14.04:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

**Note**: you can play mp4 files in Totem because it uses the 1.0 gstreamer plugins.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't installed certain mp4 codecs in your system.

I can't say which plugin you are missing. I can only say you are missing a plugin.

Installing all the restricted plugins will solve the issue.

Open your Terminal and execute this command:

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Now it should work.